# Javascript data parsing in IE vs other browsers... It seems kinda screwed up. What's the deal?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

Firstly, when I say other browsers I really only mean Firefox because that's all I tested in.

Internet Explorer can parse a date followed by a single character as a proper date.  Whereas Firefox behaves as I'd expect.

For example...

```
var dateString = new Date("1/1/2010f");
alert(dateString);
```

In IE it will alert...

Thu Dec 31 21:00:00 UTC-0900 2009

Whereas in FF is will spit out...

"Invalid Date"

I first noticed this using the jquery validation plug in.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date

It seems like it just subtracts some amount of hours off the actual date in IE when a character is appended.  I've tested in IE6 and IE8.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implementation dependent.
When Date as a "constructor" is passed a string object, it tries to build a date with its *parse* method (`Date.parse`).
That method shall parse strings returned by `Date.toString()` and `Date.toUTCString()`, which both return formats varying with the implementation. And this is how the ECMAScript standard says it should be.
I remember reading this in "the Rhino book" (Tommy Flanagan's great javascript book).

In practice, it might very well turn out everyone except IE does it the same way, but I haven't tested thoroughly.
Also, it is a bit much if IE tries to parse whatever one throws at it and produces a Date object out of ascii soup.

Comment: Thank ya.  It may be worth noting that it can't parse everything.  1/1/2010ff can't be parsed for example.  It's a bummer because it means that the jquery validation plug-in won't cover the bases for IE because all it really does to validate dates is it creates a new Date object with the date string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer uses a different parsing mechanism, which may or may not be documented, and may be very broken in some or many cases.

Comment: wtf.  That's all there is to it eh?  I would have expected this from IE6, but IE8 not so much.